# Are two free hands required to throw a two-handed ranged weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ranged-attack

I have a character who routinely uses a shield.  He has an *Efficient Quiver* and there are some spears in the quiver.

Spears are two-handed melee weapons and have a range increment of 20 feet.

Can I, while wearing a shield, draw a spear from my *Efficient Quiver* and make a ranged attack with it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### You only need one hand to throw a spear

The spear is listed under „two-handed melee weapons“ because you need two hands to wield it in **melee**. It doesn’t say that it takes only one hand to use a spear as a thrown weapon – but this is simply self-evident. Throwing a spear with two hands doesn’t make any sense at all.

You can draw a spear from the quiver as a move action and throw as a standard action. You can do this with one hand while holding a shield in the other.

---

The rules text about [thrown weapons](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#thrownWeapons) which states that "throwing a two-handed weapon is a full-round action" only refers to weapons that are *not designed to be thrown*. This becomes clear when you read on. The last two sentences of the entry state "Regardless of the type of weapon, such an attack scores a threat only on a natural roll of 20 and deals double damage on a critical hit. Such a weapon has a range increment of 10 feet." But a spear, for example, does triple damage on a critical hit and has a range increament of 20 ft.

To eliminate any uncertainties the *Rules Compendium* clarifies this rule (emphasis mine):

> It’s possible to throw a melee weapon that isn’t designed to be thrown
> (one that doesn’t have a numeric entry in the Range Increment column
> on the table where its statistics are delineated), but a creature that
> does so takes a –4 penalty on the attack roll. Throwing a light or
> onehanded weapon that isn’t designed to be thrown is a standard
> action, and **throwing a two-handed weapon
> that isn’t designed to be thrown is a full-round action**.

*Rules Compendium (p 150)*

Attacking with a ranged weapon generally is a standard action. It is not a full-round action to throw a spear.

Comment: "It doesn’t say that it takes only one hand to use a spear as a thrown weapon – but this is simply self-evident." - so you don't have a citation that throwing a two-handed melee weapon is a one-handed action?

Comment: @Yakk I don’t say that throwing a two-handed melee weapon is a one-handed action in general. I just refer to the spear - which is actually the _only_ two-handed melee weapon in the core rules with a range increament and, thus, also designed to be thrown. The rules don’t say how many hands you need if you use it as a ranged weapon. – But ... have you ever tried to throw a spear with both hands?

Answer (score 7):

### Throwing a spear is a full round action

This is under [Thrown Weapons](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#thrownWeapons) in the rules:

> Daggers, clubs, shortspears, spears, darts, javelins, throwing axes, light hammers, tridents, shuriken, and nets are thrown weapons. [...] Throwing a light or one-handed weapon is a standard action, while **throwing a two-handed weapon is a full-round action**.

Since drawing the spear from the *quiver* is not a free action<sup>1</sup>, you cannot in the same round draw and throw the spear (wether you have a shield in your other hand, or not), as a full-round action only allows you to take free actions and a 5-foot step.

---

<sup>1</sup> Drawing a weapon [is a movement action](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Action_Types). Only ammunition for bows can be drawn [as a free action](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Weapon_Categories#Ammunition).

P.S. **Aside on wether you can throw the spear with one hand**

Weapons are categorized as Light, One-Handed, Two-Handed **melee** weapons in the rules, that is the handedness applies to their effective use *as a melee weapon*:

> **Light, One-Handed, and Two-Handed Melee Weapons** 
> This designation is a measure of how much effort it takes to wield a weapon in combat. It indicates whether **a melee weapon**, when wielded by a character of the weapon’s size category, is considered a light weapon, a one-handed weapon, or a two-handed weapon. 
> *Two-Handed*
> Two hands are required to use a two-handed **melee weapon** effectively.

The rules are not explicit about not needing both hands when using these weapons as thrown weapons, but (a) they only demand two hands to use them as a melee weapon effectively, (b) at least for spears, the mechanics of throwing make no sense for using two hands and (c) the rules above for thrown weapons provide an alternative cost penalty (a full rund action) for throwing two-handed weapons.

So, I believe you should be able to throw the spear with one hand, but it will still take you a full-round action. For your question however, it does not matter if you carry a shield or not: you cannot draw and throw the spear in the same round, either way.

Comment: Are we sure about the sentence that specifies a full-round action? 
 It follows a sentence about throwing non-ranged weapons, and I interpreted the "full-round" sentence to also refer to non-ranged weapons.

Also, why isn't pulling a ranged weapon from a quiver a free action?  Certainly pulling an arrow from a quiver is.

Comment: I am pretty confident on that. It is under the heading for thrown weapons. The sentences imply no dependency on each other. If you threw a two handed weapon that also is not intended to be thrown, say, a greatsword, you would need a full round action, and incur a -4 pentalty on the attack roll. (I am less confident on if you can throw with a shield, i.e. one-handed. I think you can. Only missiles for bows can be drawn as a free action. Other, thrown weapons count as drawing a weapon.

Comment: The rule on ammunition is under ammunition ("When using a bow, a character can draw ammunition as a free action;"); the rule for Drawing a Weapon is under Combat > Action Types. It is a movement action.

Comment: The sentences after the full round sentence say "Regardless of the type of weapon, such an attack scores a threat only on a natural roll of 20 and deals double damage on a critical hit. Such a weapon has a range increment of 10 feet."  If those two sentences are applied to a spear, then they contradict the table that says spears have range increment 20 and are x3 on a crit.  So that sort of implies that the two sentences are referring to non-ranged weapons.  Which again makes me think the full-round sentence only applies to non-ranged weapons.

Comment: I think I now agree that drawing a spear from the Quiver is not a free action.  I suppose this is also true of javelins, which are not intended for melee use.

Comment: And I can see your point about the sentence being enclosed by sentences that talk about improvised thrown weapons, that possibly indicating it also refers to improvised weapons only. In that reading, if it would not cost a full-round action, I'm however less sure if you still could throw it when you have a shield, as then there is no ofsetting penalty for throwing 2-handed weapons with one hand. It still makes sense from real-world logic, and from the description of needing two hands for melee, but less so from game balance perspective.

Comment: Since the *Efficient Quiver* specified that, "once the owner has filled it, the quiver can produce any item she wishes, as if from a regular quiver or scabbard." Thus the Quick Draw feat, or any other effect that allows drawing a melee weapon as a free action would work. Of course, that's not exactly what was asked, so consider me as emulating KRyan for this comment.

Comment: The Rules Compendium (p 150) clarifies that throwing a two-handed weapon is a full-round action only in the case that the weapon "isn’t designed to be thrown".

Comment: @Peregrin Thanks for digging this up. I upvoted your answer